# How to add a new directory/folder in a package in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to simply add a new directory in a package in my Android Studio project (I'm new to AS and Android dev). I want to categorize some java files and my hierarchy is: app/src/main/java/com.company.foo.bar and I want to add a folder under bar. I right-clicked on com.company.foo.bar and selected New->Folder->Java Folder (I took a guess that this was the correct way). After doing so, a dialog popped up with no way to even name the new folder, so I clicked "Finish" to see what would happen, and it just started doing a gradle build and whirled around for over 15 minutes. I canceled but I think it might have messed something up. There's no new folder.

What is the correct way to simply add a new directory to a package in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click an existing package and choose New -> Package on Android Studio 3.2.1.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: a package in a package?

Comment: Good question but it does seem to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with trial-by-error. I just right-clicked on the Java folder, selected New->Java Class, then in the dialog, typed the package name that already exists and added an extra name for the namespace. This generated the folder/directory/package or whatever you want to call it. Android Studio is so convoluted. There's a New Folder, New Directory, New Package, that's not really apparent at what it does until you try it (and mess up your project). I tried New Folder and I have no idea what it did other than kicking off a build that lasted 15 minutes. Ugh.